# combn on grouped DT returns error "n < m"

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, correlation, combn

I have a data set with 31557 observations, and the variables Order.number and Materials. I'm trying to run this in R:

First:

```
DT <- data.table(Order.number=X$Order.number, Materials=X$Materials)
setorder(DT, Order.number, Materials)
```

Then:

```
library(data.table)    
ans <- DT[, as.data.table(do.call(rbind, combn(Materials, 2, simplify=FALSE))), 
      by=Order.number][,
                       .N, by=.(V1, V2)]
```

But I get the error in `combn(Materials, 2, simplify = FALSE) : n < m`

It works if I just use random generated table. So could it be something to do with the dataset I have?

EDIT: I tried with [meaning of combn error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570399/meaning-of-combn-error-error-in-funxi-n-m-in-r), but getting "Error in do.call(rbind, function(x) if (length(x) > 1) { : 
  second argument must be a list"

```
ans <- DT[, as.data.table(do.call(rbind, function(x)
  if(length(x)>1) {
    combn(Materials, 2, simplify=FALSE)
  }
  else x)), 
  by=Order.number][,
  .N, by=.(V1, V2)]
```

Comment: What is `length(Materials)` returning?

Comment: Do you mean length(DT$Materials) ? It is returning 31557

Comment: Possible duplicate of [meaning of combn error: Error in FUN(X\[\[i\]\], ...) : n < m in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570399/meaning-of-combn-error-error-in-funxi-n-m-in-r)

Comment: No one that can help?

Comment: In your `if` it should be `if(length(x)>1) {
combn(x, 2, simplify=FALSE)
}`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It says:
Error in do.call(rbind, function(x) if (length(x) > 1) { : 
  second argument must be a list

Comment: Clearly you have some value of grouping variable `Order.number` in your DT giving a group of length 1 or less, hence `combn(Materials, 2...)` complains that n < m. You can easily diagnose which group has length 1 with `DT[, .N, by=Order.number] [N==1]`

Comment: Feel free to upvote answers you found useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you have some value of grouping variable `Order.number` in your DT giving a group of length 1 or less, hence `combn(Materials, 2...)` complains that n < m.

You can easily diagnose which group has length 1 with `DT[, .N, by=Order.number] [N==1]`.

Then either exclude those from your summary, or write a wrapper for combn that does nothing when the input length n < m.

(Arguably `combn` should have an enhance non-default option to selectively squelch the error, when applied to groups of length n < 2, as is likely to happen when run on a grouped df/dt)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some NA values in Materials?

Otherwise your code works for me

```
#generate some random data
X<-data.frame(Order.number=rep(letters[1:10],3), Materials=rep(letters[11:20],3))

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Order.number=X$Order.number, Materials=X$Materials)
setorder(DT, Order.number, Materials)

ans <- DT[, as.data.table(do.call(rbind, combn(Materials, 2, simplify=FALSE))), 
      by=Order.number][,
                       .N, by=.(V1, V2)]
```